# What are some good Perl debugging methods?

Tags: perl, debugging, programming-languages, cpan

Are there other ways for debugging Perl programs apart from `Data::Dumper` and `perl -d`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Available tools for debugging](http://debugger.perl.org/tools.html)

There are several tools available in Perl for debugging and similar tasks.

---

Built-in command line debugger.

```
perl -d yourcode.pl
```

---

[Devel::ptkdb](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::ptkdb)

Perl/Tk based graphical debugger by Andrew E. Page.

---

[Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/)

This a free tool running both on Linux and Windows written in [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)). Source code is not 
available.

---

[Rx: A Regex Debugger for Perl](http://perl.plover.com/Rx/)

The Perl Regex debugger and an article about it written by Mark Jason Dominus.

---

[A GUI for the Perl Debugger](http://curtmckelvey.tripod.com/perldbgui/)

Comment: + WishPerl  - is nice one too

Answer (score 13):

There are lots of things out there to help you:

- [Devel::Trace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trace) - print every line that executes
- [Carp::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::REPL) - drop into a REPL`*` when the code throws a warning
- [Devel::ebug](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::ebug) - a debugger you can control from Perl code
- [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Enbugger) - use a debugger at runtime regardless of whether your process was started with debugging

Comment: * REPL = Read, Eval, Print Loop (== interactive interpreter)

Answer (score 9):

I like [Devel::Trace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trace). Basically it gives you an execution dump, showing you the code paths.

On another side, [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is all the rage now, so you could also be interested in profiling tools like [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) for highly advanced testing. See this [Tim Bunce's blog post](http://blog.timbunce.org/2008/07/15/nytprof-v2-a-major-advance-in-perl-profilers/) for an interesting overview.

Answer (score 8):

I use [ActiveState Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/) for step-by-step debugging.

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) has a step by step debugger for its [EPIC plugin](http://www.epic-ide.org/).

Personally I prefer the ActiveState version.  It just seems more solid and stable, but it does cost (and work is paying for me).  If it was my money then I would use Eclipse and EPIC as these are free.

Answer (score 6):

The best debugging aids are small routines, short scopes, limited side effects, and lots of tests. Stop bugs before they hatch.

Answer (score 5):

My usual range of tools is:

- print statements and Data::Dumper for simple cases
- perl -d

That's usually enough. There is [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/); I heard it's quite nice, but never played with it.

For some tasks (which are not really debugging, but close to it) I use [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf).

Comment: Suggestion: s/Data::Dumper/Data::Dump/. It's way more nutritious.

Answer (score 4):

Some people use `print` statements in order to see what's going on in sections of a program that aren't doing what they thought the code would do. (I.e., as a way of checking what is actually contained in a variable at a given point of execution.)

Comment: I like to use "warn" instead of "print" so it goes to stderr and not stdout. "print STDERR" works too but needs more typing.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're doing, [Log::Log4perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl) provides an easy way to manage the 'print' style of debugging particularly in bigger applications:

- provides various logging levels (Debug, Info, Error, Warning, and Fatal)
- controlled from configuration files (easy to have debugging on development box, only errors on production box, for example)
- configurable by sections of your application (e.g., web application in one log file at one level, [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) scripts in another at a different log level)
- configurable by class - easy to quieten noisy modules, or add detailed debugging to somewhere deep within an application

Comment: Most people use Log::Log4perl when Log::Message (a core module) would do.

Answer (score 3):

Test::More for writing basic tests, Hook::LexWrap, Test::MockObject, Test::Deep, Test::MockTime, Test::WWW::Mechanize and many others for advanced tests.

Attribute::Signature for checking sub parameters. Carp::Assert for contract-based programming.

Devel::Ebug::Wx or Devel::ptkdb (and soon better support in [Padre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padre_(software))) can be used for easier debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs, hands down:

```
emacs my_script.pl
M-x perldb
```

Emacs will prompt you:

```
Run perldb (like this): perl my_script.pl
Hit enter (or add command line switches)
```

Now use the debugger as usual.

Type 'c' to continue executing the code, which will now follow your code as you execute through it.

Emacs is fully integrated with its debuggers and will make debugging Perl code nearly trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Use *Devel::SimpleTrace* for the most elegant seamless stateless-debugging.

```
perl -MDevel::SimpleTrace -we'warn "main"; sub foo{ warn "outer"; sub { warn "inner" } }; foo()->()'
```

Answer (score 2):

During development, I like to embed printf statements in strategic places (not too many) which are enabled with a debug flag like this:

```
printf("h='$h', j='$j', ... (%d)\n", __LINE__) if $debug;
```

where the debug flag is defined at the top of the script:

```
my $debug = $ENV{DEBUG} || 0;
```

Now instead of having to remember to comment out all of the printf lines, I just run the script as follows:

```
DEBUG=1 ./script.pl
```

After testing when everything is ready for production, the debug lines can be removed:

```
cat script.pl | grep -v 'if $debug;'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like `perl -d` then [Devel::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL) and [Carp::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::REPL) are both nice alternatives.

Comment: pity Devel::REPL requires the 400 pound Moose (and various MooseX modules), and Carp::REPL depends on Devel::REPL

Comment: And this is a problem because...?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm a big fan of [Smart::Comments](https://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Comments). It makes tracing dead simple, and there isn't any need to strip it out again, either.

```
use Smart::Comments -ENV;
...
sub myroutine {
    my ($self, @args) = @_ ;
    ### args: @args
    ...
}
```

If `Smart_Comments` has been set in the environment, the lines commencing with ### are converted to debug output, with `Dumper()` used automagically. If the environment variable isn't set, the debug stuff is completely inert.

It has heaps of features and will produce progress bars, warnings, abort conditions as well as plain old debug output.

Appropriate tests are all good, and I'm not dismissing a good [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (TDD) development methodology, but when trying to get to the bottom of an existing bug, *Smart::Comments* is the go.

Comment: And it is a source filter, hence fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I use

```
perl -d
```

for debugging.

You can also use the *Eclipse Perl Integration* (EPIC) plug-in for Eclipse. It offers a rich debugging environment available and integrated with the EPIC Perl development environment. You can use it, and it is generally helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Writing tests can mostly decrease debugging time, I think.

Answer (score 0):

[Some Other methods](http://cgi2.cs.rpi.edu/~lallip/perl/fall05/debugging.shtml)

```
CGI::Dump

Benchmark

Command-line options 

__DATA__ & <DATA> 

$.

__FILE__ & __LINE__ 

warn() & die()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Debug::Statements](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debug::Statements) provides an easy way to insert and enable/disable print statements for debugging.

The d() function prints the name of your variable, its value, and your subroutine name. The implementation been optimized to minimize programmer keystrokes.

Here is sample code to get you started:

```
my $myvar = 'some value';
my @list = ('zero', 1, 'two', "3");
my %hash = ('one' => 2, 'three' => 4);

use Debug::Statements;
my $d = 1;
d "Hello, World!";
d '$myvar';
d '@list %hash';
```

Output:

```
DEBUG sub mysub:  Hello, World!
DEBUG sub mysub:  $myvar = 'some value'
DEBUG sub mysub:  @list = [
  'zero',
  1,
  'two',
  '3'
]
DEBUG sub mysub:  %hash = {
  'one' => 2,
  'three' => 4
}
```

Many options are available to customize the output. Full documentation can be found on [CPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN).