# What is the best and useful debug tool in Linux environment for Perl and C++ scripts?

Tags: c++, linux, perl, eclipse, debugging

What is the best and useful debug tool in Linux environment for Perl and C++ scripts?

In related to that, does anyone know the differences between Eclipse to DDD tools?

Thank you,

YoDar.

Comment: You have two questions there, so you should separate them into distinct queries for Stackoverflow.

Comment: for perl: did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037583/what-are-some-good-perl-debugging-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't do Perl.

But I do Eclipse & DDD.

Eclipse is an IDE (which also supports Perl). IF you use C/C++, for instance, it supports the GDB. If you can compile Perl, it will probably support that too, which means that you can step through your code, line by line, examining the call stack, looking at variables, changing their values, etc.

DDD is a front-end for GDB, so it can do all of that debugging stuff, but it is not an IDE that will let you edit & compile your code.

Generally, Eclipse is more than good enough, but when I get into complicated lists or structures with lots of pointers, I love DDD for this single picture - which speaks ten thousand words ...

[image]

From http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/all.png

Answer (score 1):

`use warnings;` and `-Wall`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You may debug perl in console, but it's not the most user-friendly way

`perl -d script.pl`

In DDD documentation it says they're frontend for perl debugger too, so I guess you may configure it to use perl debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perl: Eclipse [Epic](http://www.epic-ide.org/) with PadWalker module installed for debugging
2. C++: Eclipse CDT