# Run a Perl script in debugging mode

Tags: linux, perl

How can I run a Perl script in debugging mode (like "bash -x" for shell scripts)?

I tried the `-w` parameter like the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

But it didn't work out.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work out"? Please show how you tried to run your script and what the error was.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  The `-w` will have worked, but it doesn't run the debug (it adds warnings while Perl is compiling the script).  See [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) for how to run and use the Perl debugger.  Note that a question that says "it didn't work" without showing the code, the actual result and the expected result is not really answerable -- such questions are often closed as 'off topic'.

Comment: "-w" activates warnings in perl. See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) for debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to turn on tracing in perl (equivalent to bash -x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852395/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-tracing-in-perl-equivalent-to-bash-x)

Answer (score 6):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
```

are enough IMO.

If you want to use debugger then check out: [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)

You can use built in command line debugger as:

```
perl -d yourcode.pl
```

Also see:

- [Perl debugging tools](http://debugger.perl.org/tools.html)
- [What are some good Perl debugging methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037583/what-are-some-good-perl-debugging-methods)
- [Debugging Perl scripts (article by Gabor)](http://perlmaven.com/debugging-perl-scripts)
- [An Introduction to the Perl Debugger (by Joseph Brenner)](http://obsidianrook.com/devnotes/talks/perl_debugger/)
- [Padre Perl5Debugger](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/Features/Perl5Debugger)

Answer (score 5):

`perl -Dt` is kind of like `bash -x` , but you need to specifically compile `perl` to allow that kind of tracing.

But with any `perl`, you can run a script using the debugger:

```
perl -d yourscriptname yourscriptargs
```

See [perldebtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html) for starters.

Answer (score 4):

For `bash -x` style trace of a Perl script, check out `Devel::DumpTrace`. Example:

demo.pl:

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl
      # demo.pl: a demonstration of Devel::DumpTrace
      $a = 1;
      $b = 3;
      $c = 2 * $a + 7 * $b;
      @d = ($a, $b, $c + $b);
```

program output:

```
      $ perl -d:DumpTrace demo.pl
      >>>>> demo.pl:3:        $a:1 = 1;
      >>>>> demo.pl:4:        $b:3 = 3;
      >>>>> demo.pl:5:        $c:23 = 2 * $a:1 + 7 * $b:3;
      >>>>> demo.pl:6:        @d:(1,3,26) = ($a:1, $b:3, $c:23 + $b:3);
```